# How to make your API run only when the containers view is shown?

Tags: ios, swift, uicontainerview

I am using a 5 container view inside one view controller. All container view are of same size (same width and same Height). Different API are performed on different container view.

The approach which I am implementing is showing and hiding the container view as per the button action.

Example : On click of button one, ContainerViewOne is shown and rest are hidden.

Problem which I am facing is that when the view controller is loaded all the api in all container view is called at the same time. I want it to run when the container view is shown. Can anyone help me with the same?

Comment: Can we see some code?  You should be doing this wherever you are showing and hiding the various containers.

Answer (score 1):

**Try This One**

I think you find something like this.

1) create APICaliing and data reload function in yourContainerViewController.

2) Find yourContainerViewController from YourMainViewController childViewControllers.

3) call APICalling Function.

```
@IBAction func btnClickEvent(_ sender: UIButton) { 

    //Find yourContainerViewController from your all childViewControllers
    for vcObj in self.childViewControllers{
        if vcObj.isKind(of: yourContainerViewController.self){
            // Here your api call and reload data inside this function
            // apiCallFunction() Function create in you yourContainerViewController and put api calling and data reload code in this function.
            (vcObj as! yourContainerViewController).apiCallFunction() 
            break
        }
    }

}
```

Happy To Help You :)